# Removing item from collection also removing all from related collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Excuse the slightly confusing title I didn't know how best to summarize my coding problem.

I am using entity framework to do INSERTS and UPDATES using a collection of objects. Sometimes one item has to be inserted because it doesn't exist and sometimes it's an update because it is in the database. I compare my collection with the data context to know which is which.

```
public modelClaimDatabase EditPersonDependants(modelClaimDatabase Model)
{
    try
    {
        using (var CasaLatinaEntities = new CasaLatinaEntities())
        {
            // Do dependants logic - first find out if there are any
            if (Model.ModelDependants.Count > 0)
            {
                // collection of dependants from Database
                var qDependants = CasaLatinaEntities.tblDependants;
                // collection of dependants from Model
                var ModelDependants = Model.ModelDependants;

                // GET all dependants from the Model that do match the DB
                var UpdateList =
                    from m in ModelDependants
                    where qDependants.Any(q => q.PersonID == m.PersonID)
                    select m;

                // GET all dependants from the Model that don't match the DB
                var InsertList =
                    from m in ModelDependants
                    where !qDependants.Any(q => q.PersonID == m.PersonID)
                    select m;

                if (InsertList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var dependant in InsertList)
                    {
                        Model.ModelDependants.Remove(dependant);
                        CreateDependant(dependant, Model);
                        Model.ModelDependants.Add(dependant);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return Model;
}
```

When I use this code

```
Model.ModelDependants.Remove(dependant);
```

This line of code

```
if (InsertList.Count() > 0)
```

No longer has anything to enumerate through. However I am not removing from InsertList I am removing from my Model.

The reason I am doing this is because in

```
CreateDependant(dependant, Model);
```

I am making changes to that object which I then want to add back to my model with the new data. So I will have a collection of objects which will say either "This was a new row that was added" or "You have updated this row".

Does anyone have a better way of writing this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't say for sure because I'm not setup to test it, but I wonder if creating a new list from your results would fix the `Count` issue.

Calling `ToList()` creates a new list, so when you remove an item from `ModelDependants`, it shouldn't also be removed from `InsertList`.

```
var InsertList = (from m in ModelDependants
                  where !qDependants.Any(q => q.PersonID == m.PersonID)
                  select m).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I made that change and it works perfectly.